# Turning IMGs into divs with background-image (preg_replace)

Tags: php, wordpress, image, preg-replace, src

I'm trying something out but as I'm not versed in PHP it feels like smashing my head against random walls.

I need to alter the output of image tags. I want to replace the img tag for a div with a background image, to achieve sort of this effect.

I'm working around this function, in functions.php. This only takes the full image code and outputs it into the background-image url. I would need to extract the SRC.

```
function turnItIntoDiv( $content ) {

// A regular expression of what to look for.
   $pattern = '/(<img([^>]*)>)/i';
// What to replace it with. $1 refers to the content in the first 'capture group', in parentheses above
   $replacement = '<div class="full-image" style="background-image: url("$1")"></div>';

// run preg_replace() on the $content
   $content = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $content );

// return the processed content

   return $content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'turnItIntoDiv' );
```

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would by fine to split.

```
if (preg_match("/img/i",$content))
{
    ..
    $pattern = '/src="([^"]+)"/i';   
    ..
```

Then you will get exact file name. Height of div should be set.

Whole code - matching all images:

```
if (preg_match("/img/i",$content))
{
  if (preg_match_all('/src[ ]?=[ ]?"([^"]+)"/i',$content,$matches))
  { 
    foreach ($matches[1] as $i => $match)
    {
       $replacement = '<div class="full-image" style="background-image: url(\'' . trim($match) . '\')"></div>';

        $content = preg_replace("~(<img(.*){$matches[0][$i]}[^>]+>)~i",$replacement,$content);
     }
  }
}
```

! div height must be set

Comment: It looks very good but it's spilling a blank page, any chance there could be some typo in there?

Comment: Still spitting a blank page. Do you know what it could be?

Comment: I'm sorry, how can I do that?

Comment: Nothing... Sorry for the hassle and thanks for the try

Comment: Still blank! How can I isolate the problem? Any way to know if the error is in the first or second conditional?

Comment: Confirmed: Hay un imagen aquí

Comment: The div has a height set, if I replace in the inspector everything's fine

Comment: It works!!! It's just blocking the text content, and only replacing one image. You know why?

Comment: If I change both preg_match to preg_match_all, it outputs a div but nothing in the background-image url

Comment: So close!! Check this error: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/' [file] =>

Comment: I was wrong, sorry! It does show the 5 images. Now I'm missing the text content only

Comment: As I commented the $content line, this is normal i guess. But if I uncomment, no content is returned. Is there something wrong in that function?

Comment: Exactly. Echo $replacement shows the images. $content = preg_... spits blank by itself

Comment: Is there `return $content;` at the end? and did you update to: `preg_replace("~(<img(.*) ... `